# (Error : RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally) when restoring SQL Backup from Standard edition to Developer Edition (Both 2017 Versions!)

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, sql-server-2017

The instances have the following versions

**Source -->**

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU25) (KB5003830) - 14.0.3401.7 (X64)
> Jun 25 2021 14:02:48   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 
> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

The database has compatibility level 2017 (140)

**Target -->**

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017
> 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition
> (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 Standard 6.2  (Build 9200: )
> (Hypervisor)

the database is almost 600GB

When we tried a backup without compression then at the restore we get (no backup sets available to restore) in a few seconds

When we tried a backup with compression then at the restore we get  (RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. ) after hours of reading the file.

Both SSMS are latests versions.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand
I patched the target to the same CU level. Still same results. The files were transfered to the target  by another technician using a VMware cloud due to very big sizes. Is the possibility high,    durring the transfer the data to be corrupted ?  in event log i saw the follwing --> (The backup data at the end of "C:\SQL\Data\testnew" is incorrectly formatted ) .. Should i take this for sure that we are talking about corrupted file so the transfer has to be made again ?

Comment: Can you [edit] teh post and add the full text of the error message?

Comment: Have you tried running a RESTORE VERIFYONLY to confirm the backup media is valid? That might provide more helpful messages if there is a problem with the backup file.